# How to get the closest multiple of 5 in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to round the returned number to closest multiple of 5 in this PHP.

```
return number_format(($entry['69']*$entry['68.2']*0.7), 0, ".", ",").'€' ;
```

How to get it correctly?

Comment: by implementing an algorithm. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `round($val/5)*5`:

```
$val = round($entry['69'] * $entry['68.2'] * 0.7 / 5) * 5;
return number_format($val, 0, ".", ",").'€' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom function with greater detail of how everything is happening. You can change anything here if you need to update your code.

```
<?php
    //Enter your code here, enjoy!

function roundClosest($num){

    $helpVar = round($num/5);
    $helpVar2 = $helpVar * 5;

    if($num - $helpVar2 > 2.9){
        $res = ($helpVar + 1) * 5;
    }
    else{
        $res = $helpVar * 5;
    }

    return $res;

}

echo roundClosest(62.34);
echo "\n";
echo roundClosest(63.67);
```

> Output:
>
> 60
>
> 65

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you! above reply worked well for me, I guess this one too for anyone that needs it.